# How to get custom category attribute value on checkout and order page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom attribute for my category. I want to get that attribute on my checkout page and order page but the value is not getting after cart page. I have also tried by using session variable but it is overwriting the previous category attribute value if there is more than one product added in cart.

here is my code for session variable written in **default.phtml**

```
$id = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('Catalog/product')->load($id);
$categorysku = $product->getCategory();
$product->getCategoryIds();
echo $categorysku->getData('category-sku');// required category attribute value
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not a better idea to persist the custom category attribute value(s) in the order line?

In that case you create an observer that is triggered on

```
 sales_quote_item_set_product
```

and it will look like:

```
 class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
 {
     public function salesQuoteItemSetCustomCategoryAttribute($observer)
     {
        // Your save custom category attribute to order line logic...
        return $this;
     }
  }
```